# Fancybox group images without duplicates

Tags: jquery, fancybox

How would I group multiple images without any duplicates using fancybox? I have tried using the rel="group" although this either displays a list of the recent images.

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul>    
    <li>        
        <a rel="group1" class="fancy" title="Custom title" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930.jpg">            <img alt="" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930_m.jpg">        </a>        
        <h2><a rel="group1" class="fancy" title="Custom title" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930.jpg">Test title about image</a></h2>    
    </li>    
    <li>        
        <a rel="group2" class="fancy" title="Custom title" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930.jpg">            
            <img alt="" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930_m.jpg">        
        </a>        
        <h2><a rel="group2" class="fancy" title="Custom title" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930.jpg">Test title about image</a></h2>    
    </li>    
    <li>        
        <a rel="group3" class="fancy" title="Custom title" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930.jpg">            
            <img alt="" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930_m.jpg">        
        </a>        
        <h2><a rel="group3" class="fancy" title="Custom title" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930.jpg">Test title about image</a></h2>    
    </li>    
    <li>        
        <a rel="group4" class="fancy" title="Custom title" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930.jpg">            
            <img alt="" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930_m.jpg">        
        </a>        
        <h2><a rel="group4" class="fancy" title="Custom title" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930.jpg">Test title about image</a></h2>    
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are missing the fanybox JS...

Comment: Yeah jsfiddle is running really slow and not uploading the JS. I have removed this. Pretty pointless because it's just a basic fancybox example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now wasn't that too easy:

```
<li>        
        <a rel="group1" class="fancy" title="Custom title" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930.jpg">            
            <img alt="" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930_m.jpg">        
        </a>        
        <h2><a rel="group2" class="fancy" title="Custom title" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930.jpg">Test title about image</a></h2>    
    </li>
```

Comment: Yes, you can create two seperate groups, like this - http://jsfiddle.net/K44HR/1/ - but my first demo would work better if using elastic openEffect/closeEffect, because animation would start from thumbnail for both links

Answer (score 4):

You could trigger click event of the "fancy" link, like this - http://jsfiddle.net/K44HR/

(adjust jQuery selectors if needed)

Comment: It's not for my problem, but it helped me.I solved double images with Fancybox by adjusting jQuery selector.Big Big Thanks.